# Potential issue with Couchbase paging

Tags: pagination, nosql, couchbase

It may be too much turkey over the holidays, but I've been thinking about a potential problem that we could have with Couchbase.

Currently we paginate based on time, but I'm thinking a similar issue could occur with other values used for paging for example the atomic counter. I'll try to explain best I can, this would only occur in a load balanced environment.

For example say we have 4 servers load balanced and storing data to our Couchbase cluster. We sort our records based on timestamps currently. If any of the 4 servers writing the data starts to lag behind the others than our pagination would possibly be missing records when retrieving client side. A SQL DB auto-increment and timestamps for example can be created when the record is stored to the DB which will avoid similar issues. Using a NoSql DB like Couchbase you define the data you need to retrieve on before it is stored to the DB. So what I am getting at is if there is a delay in storing to the DB and you are retrieving in a pagination fashion while this delay has occurred, you run the real possibility of missing data. Since we are paging that data may never be viewed.

Interested in what other thoughts people have on this.

---

**EDIT****
Response to Andrew:

Example a facebook or pintrest type app is storing data to a DB, they have many load balanced servers from the frontend writing to the db. If for some reason writing is delayed its a non issue with a SQL DB because a timestamp or auto increment happens when the data is actually stored to the DB. There will be no missing data when paging. asking for 1-7 will give you data that is only stored in the DB, 7-* will contain anything that is delayed because an auto-increment value has not been created for that record becuase it is not actually stored.

In Couchbase its different, you actually get your auto increment value (atomic counter) and then save it. So for example say a record is going to be stored as atomic counter number 4. For some reasons this is delayed in storing to the DB. Other servers are grabbing 5, 6, 7 and storing that data just fine. The client now asks for all data between 1 and 7, 4 is still not stored. Then the next paging request is 7 to *. 4 will never be viewed.

Is there a way around this? Can it be modelled differently in CB, or is this just a potential weakness in CB when needing to page results. As I mentioned are paging is timestamp sensitive.

Comment: Couchbase is not a transactional database system. So, if your use-case requires the database to be in a consistent state at all times it is queried (e.g. you are worried about records missing from a page), then  Couchbase is not the solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

Michael,

Couchbase is an eventually consistent database with respect to views. It is ACID with respect to documents. There are durability interfaces that let you manage this. This means that you can rest assured you won't lose data and that indexes will catch up eventually.

In my experience with Couchbase, you need to expect that the nodes will never be in-sync. There are many things the database is doing, such as compaction and replication. The most important thing you can do to enhance performance is to put your views on a separate spindle from the data. And you need to ensure that your main data spindles across your cluster can sustain between 3-4 times your ingestion bandwidth. Also, make sure your main document key hashes appropriately to distribute the load.

It sounds like you are discussing a situation where the data exists in your system for less time than it takes to be processed through the view system. If you are removing data that fast, you need either a bigger cluster or faster disk arrays. Of the two choices, I would expand the size of your cluster. I like to think of Couchbase as building a RAIS, Redundant Array of Independent Servers. By expanding the cluster, you reduce the coincidence of hotspots and gain disk bandwidth. My ideal node has two local drives, one each for data and views, and enough RAM for my working set.

Anon,
Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew,thanks for your post. I'm not concerned so much around views and we aren't removing data, sorry if you got that impression. The concern is that if we are paging and the web tier is delayed there is no timestamp or auto increment like a SQL db that can have the record appear in the next paging result. This data is set at the web teir and you are hoping the write is fast enough from when you set the data to when you read it again. Let me know if you need a better example. Trying to think of a way around this potential issue.

Comment: Michael, it isn't clear what you mean by paging then. Any item saved to CB is available immediately. It only takes measurable time if you use views. What do you mean by pagination? Andrew

Comment: The question I had wasn't related to views processing the data, which could be mitigated with a performance hit using the stale parameter. What my thoughts and concerns are around is that Couchbase has no field like an autoincrement or timestamp set by Couchbase itself when the data is actually stored, unlike a SQL DB. Just trying to figure out if there is a way around that. It's really about modelling the data in Couchbase to avoid that issue. In a SQL db timestamp can be applied when data is actually stored, in coucbase you define it in the model and then store.

Comment: Andrew refer to my edit in my original post. I tried to layout a better example.

Comment: Michael, you want the timestamp to reflect when the data is durably stored on disk versus when it was stored in the cache. Couchbase is going to respond to your query from the cache. Is the accuracy you are expecting actually required? You appear to think so but haven't motivated why? You gain some things from a NoSQL database, like excellent horizontal scaling, and lose others, like this precise storage time. Is it really an issue? In answer to your question, no you cannot modify the data at write time. You can stack writes and the last one wins when the first gets to the head of the queue.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Have a look at the edit above in my original post.